# Is it necessary to use boilerplates such as MEAN, NG-boilerplate etc

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, boilerplate

Is it necessary to use boilerplates to create an web app using angualrjs?
i just dont understand how to use them. Is there any other way? if so what can I do to create apps without using boilerplates.

best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not !
Your can just use AngularJS with regular HTML elements and nothing else.

Boilerplates are good for open projects, because it makes your code / HTML easily usable by anyone.

If you want to create a Web app alone or to discover AngularJS, you don't have to bother with boilerplates. If you are going to share it at any point though, it could be a good idea to use a template.

Comment: Hi, I have spent weeks trying to figure to install boilerplates like MEAN and ng-boilerplate and when I finally installed them they were so confusing. I want to create a task management site which people would be able to use. I have been going crazy with this boilerplate thing thank you for clearing that out. I just have one question when you say share with someone what do you mean?

Comment: @user3115683 Share your code. Not your app. If you share your projet on GitHub or something similar, it's better if it follows standards.

Answer (score 1):

**No you are not required to use any boilerplate.**

Seeing all this stuff can be quite overwhelming. If you don't know where to start, work your way through the Angular [**Tutorial**](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). All you need to do is creating a HTML document and injecting Angular.

Boilerplates are meant to kill re-occuring tasks like setting up a router or a database. Once you have wrapped your head around the basic [**concepts of Angular**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts), you can begin to dig deeper.

Comment: Hi, I have spent weeks trying to figure to install boilerplates like MEAN and ng-boilerplate and when I finally installed them they were so confusing. I want to create a task management site which people would be able to use. I have been going crazy with this boilerplate thing thank you for clearing that out. I just have one question when you say share with someone what do you mean?